# Deletion Batch file but receive cannot find desktop.ini

Tags: batch-file, cmd, delete-file

I've created a simple batch file to delete files over 14 days which is a simple command as most of you probably know so it's doing the below

```
forfiles /p "C:\%userprofile%\Downloads" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -14
```

but I keep receiving could not find C:\User\%userprofile%\downloads\desktop.ini

So I assume it's searching for the desktop.ini file but I have all folders and files unhidden. Is there a way to prevent it looking for that file and just doing as a I ask it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As Mike Nakis suggests, `del` is probably failing on `desktop.ini` because that file is typically set `+ash` (archive, system, and hidden).  The easiest solution would be just to ignore it.  It's harmless anyway.

```
forfiles /p "%userprofile%\Downloads" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del @path 2>NUL" /d -14
```

If it really bothers you and you insist on deleting it, then remove the system attribute.

```
attrib -r -s -h -a "%userprofile%\Downloads\*"
forfiles /p "%userprofile%\Downloads" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c del @path" /d -14
```

... but it'll probably just get re-created eventually anyway.  I'd just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say that you have all folders and files unhidden? You have probably instructed the windows explorer to also show hidden files, but that does not mean that the files are not hidden.

You have two options: for each file that you are about to delete, either use the `attrib` command to make sure it is not hidden prior to deleting it, or play with the `/A` option of the `del` command to make it delete everything, even hidden files.